# Python - Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument Account Kit

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, account-kit

In the Facebook docs they have mentioned that access_token consist of

AA|facebook_app_id|app_secret

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi

And the appsecret_proof is hash of access token using app secret as key

`appsecret_proof = hmac.new((app_secret).encode('ascii'), msg=access_token.encode('ascii'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`

So I am using the above generated appsecret_proof to call to the endpoint

https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.1/me/?access_token=

with appsecret_proof as the second parameter. But still I am getting Invalid AppSecret_proof provided in API argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, you need to use an user access token and hash it with app secret to get the app secret_proof and not app access token

Answer (score 0):

Your app_token appears to be incorrect, the syntax is `<app_id>|<app_secret>` -- e.g.:

```python
facebook_app_id     = '<YOUR_APP_ID>'
facebook_app_secret = '<YOUR_APP_SECRET>'
facebook_app_token  = '{}|{}'.format(facebook_app_id,facebook_app_secret)
```

You can then generate the appsecret_proof as follows:

```python
import hmac,hashlib
app_secret_proof    = hmac.new(facebook_app_secret.encode('utf-8'),
                           msg=facebook_app_token.encode('utf-8'),
                           digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```